# How to access ubuntu partition from windows using virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, virtualization

I have found links describing to do the exact opposite: accessing windows through virtualbox in ubuntu. I don't want to reboot the system everytime I want to check something small in ubuntu. I have ubuntu 12.04 and windows 8 (dual boot). How can I set up virtualbox (or any other free virtualization software) so that I can access ubuntu from windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually install Samba on the client OS, and access it as a network share from the host OS.

You may also want to have a look at the feature Shared folders in VirtualBox.

Comment: I also want to be able to access and run some apps. I guess I have to go with virtualbox, then.

Comment: Both options will provide a locally mounted file system on the host OS, you should be able to use all files/apps in the same way. If this was helpful, consider making it the accepted answer, thanks.